# php Getting Data from Database slows down the Page

Tags: php, mysql, freeze

I am using wamp server on windows. while getting a little bit of data from my database hangs my page badly. it's just like a simple post which have 1 image 1 title and a little bit discription and when I trigger the command it hangs my page badly. here is how my code looks like.

```
    <?php
    //1. Create a connection
    $connection= mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$connection){
        die("Database Connection Failed :" . mysql_error());
    }

    //2 Select a database to use
    $db_select = mysql_select_db("gat", $connection);
    if (!$db_select) {
        die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }

    ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Database Check</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        //3 perform database query
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM recent_works",$connection);
        if (!$result) {
            die("Database query failed:" . mysql_error());
        }

        //4 use returned data 
        while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
            echo "<div class='work_item'>";
            echo "<img src='{$row['image']}' alt=''>";
            echo "<h2>{$row['title']}</h2>";
            echo "<p>{$row['short_discription']}</p>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
     ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
    //5 close connection
    mysql_close($connection);
 ?>
```

Comment: use the mysqli instead of mysql because it is deprecated

Comment: your code seems to be ok..Try to restart wamp server and try again

Comment: how many records do you have in your database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetching data from a database will always involve some level of blocking. The question is how much data are you fetching. Your example indicates you are selecting everything from the table and fetching all of the data to print out onto the page. So how many rows are in the table, how much data is stored in each column, and how much of that data gets transferred to the client are all provisioning factors of speed here. Additionally, you have to consider that connecting to the database also has a cost.

Here are a few suggestions I can make to the above code:

1. Don't use the old mysql extension (mysql_* functions), but consider using the newer MySQLi extension, which can help you do things the old extension can't; like [asynchronous queries](http://php.net/mysqli.reap-async-query). It's also **highly discouraged** to use the old mysql extension in new development, since it's in plans for deprecation currently. See [MySQL: choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) in the PHP manual for more information.
2. Check [phpinfo()](http://php.net/phpinfo) to make sure you aren't using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) (which requires buffering up to a certain amount of data before it gets sent to the client). This could result in the client waiting around until there's data ready to be sent. Pushing some HTML content out to the client as soon as possible could help improve the user experience.
3. Don't use `SELECT * FROM table` in your queries, instead, consider explicitly selecting only the fields you need for each query: `SELECT image,title,short_discription FROM recent_works`
4. If there's a lot of data (more than say hundred rows maybe) consider using **pagination** and [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) the query to a certain number of rows per page view. This can greatly reduce the amount of traffic between your DBMs and PHP on a per request basis.
5. If it's a high load site consider using a [persistent database connection](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php).

Comment: man i got the solution. i was using a chrome plugin called livepage which reloads the page when it is changed. it was active so it made my page slows down :)